# Why Draw line in QGraphicScene not show but add button worked in pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

when i add pushbutton  dynamically to the QGraphicScene with a pic its work but when i use QPainter to draw a line or rectangle not show.
code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QPixmap,QPainter,QPainterPath,QBrush,QColor,QPen

class Scene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        

        self.path_item = self.addPath(QtGui.QPainterPath())

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPointF()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.scenePos()
        self.end_point = self.start_point
        self.update_path()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end_point = event.scenePos()
            self.update_path()
        super(Scene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.scenePos()
        self.update_path()
        super(Scene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def update_path(self):
        if not self.start_point.isNull() and not self.end_point.isNull():
            path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
            path.moveTo(self.start_point)
            path.lineTo(self.end_point)
            self.path_item.setPath(path)
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

    view.setMouseTracking(True)

    pix = QPixmap('assets/data.png')
    mainpic = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pix)

    scene = Scene()
    scene.addItem(mainpic)

    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think my problem in mouse event but if i disable pic in GraphicsScene draw line correctly worked.

Comment: when use QPainter its work but im using QpainterPath not woked

Comment: Because every time you call `update_path()` you're creating a **new** path.